# How to convert string variable value x='\202' into raw string value x='\\202" in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-literals

I have a variable `x` which has value `'\202'`, I want to convert x into raw_x = `'\\202'`. I have tried couple of things below, but didn't get desired output.

```
x = '\202'     #we cannot modify x = r'\202', because x is coming from other source
print(x)

raw_x = fr"{x}"
print(raw_x)

raw_x = r"{}".format(x)
print(raw_x)

raw_x = "%r" %x
print(raw_x)

raw_x = x.encode("unicode_escape").decode()
print(raw_x)
# Desire raw_x = r'\202' or raw_x = '\\202'
print("Desired raw_x output: \\202")
```

Console Output:

```
'\x82'
\x82
Desired raw_x output: `\202`
```

Comment: Where is that data coming from..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> \ooo    --> Character with octal value ooo

So it's a character, all you have to do is get it's Unicode code point number(in base 10) with [`.ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) then convert that number to octal with [`.oct()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct) which gives octal string prefixed with “0o”: (or just simply do `interested_part = f'{ord(x):o}'`)

```
x = '\202'
interested_part = oct(ord(x))[2:]
print('\\' + interested_part)
print(r'\\' + interested_part)
```

output :

```
\202
\\202
```

explanation:

```
x = '\202'
x = ord(x)
print(x)     # 130

x = oct(x)
print(x)     # 0o202

print(x[2:]) # removing the octal notation
```

Comment: I did... I learnt it now... And that's the right answer... Thanks...